# JNI error has occured and I just removed and reinstalled the jdk

Tags: java

I have this question before, but the problem is still not resolved. When running the code found below, the message "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation...", etc. I have removed and reinstalled the jdk, making sure it was up to date. I reset the variable PATH but the same error still comes up.

```
package java;
public class javautilArrays {
    public static void mian(String[] args) {
        char[] copyFrom = {'d', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd'};
        char[] copyTo = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(copyFrom, 2, 9);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

In the console terminal the following message appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where in that message does it say "A JNI error has occurred"?

Comment: Your error says `Prohibited package name: java`. BTW, your method should be called `main`, not `mian`.

Comment: The error message you actually present ("Prohibited package name: java") arises because you are trying to create a class in package `java`, per your `package java` statement.  This is not allowed.  Choose your own package name, or even omit any `package` declaration at all and thereby use the anonymous package.

Comment: there is a pop up that says the JNI error has occurred, I just closed it before. and then the rest of those exceptions showed up after in the bottom terminal. Also, I retyped this instead of just copy and pasting it, but in my program i did spell main right. and lastly i tried deleting the line "package java;" but the same error occurs, still saying at the top "Prohibited package name: java"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says "Prohibited package name: java" and if you look at the top of your code you see `package java`. This is not a valid package name, you have to change it.

The error you mentioned is not in the stack trace.

Comment: I tried deleting it, but it still said "Prohibited package name: java". What would I change it to?

Comment: Don't just delete the line, that will just move the class out of the package, but the package you created still exists. You can delete it from the project structure view in whatever ide you're using

Comment: I got it working a while ago but decided to revisit this now. It makes sense to me now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not use common names for your variables, methods and packages.
look at the first line of your code

```
package java;
```

You have to change the name of your package to something else.
You did not mention which IDE are you using to develop your program, but if you are using eclipse or netbeans you MUST recreate your project and delete this one.

In the above peace of code you have tried to add a new class to java package (native installation), which you are not allowed abviously since Java is not a OTF kind of compiler. Just change the package name from java to something else.
If you take a look at the traceback you have attached,it's calling your project unknown source.

Do not forget to accept this answer if it worked.

good luck.

Iman

Comment: Okay so I deleted all of the previous projects in the workspace folder, but they came back and I receive this message whenever I try to run my new code with the name "Joe" for my package name.
"Error retrieving content description for resource '/Switch Case/src/java/javautilArrays.java'.
File not found: C:\Users\Michael1\workspace\Switch Case\src\java\javautilArrays.java."

Comment: Got it, just had to add public static void main(String[] args) to it

Comment: You don't need to delete your project, just the package.

Comment: zar, I am pretty sure that he has not a multi package project. Projects's main packages definition is being held in project file and will not be corrected by just erasing a line form java file, thats the case in ecelipse and netbeans but I am not sure about the other IDEs

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name to something else. Make a new package and move this class to that package.